# Change the state of a <rect> element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have mapped an image. By default "fill" is red with "opacity = 0".I am accessing an api to get the following json:

```
{
"documents": [
    {
        "_id": "646fd0fbe269fac6c8374c9e",
        "id": "gid://Product/7592907636921",
        "status": false,
        "url": "https://www.store.com/products/link1"
    }
]
}
```

I would like some help, if when the url matches my mapped "href" and the status is false, the opacity is changed to 1 so that the box is marked red. And if possible, instead of completely covering it with red, cross out the square with an X.

[image]

```
<style>
.table_number{
fill: red;
opacity: 0;
}
</style>
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 540 159">
<image width="540" height="159" xlink:href="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0573/4478/6617/files/tables_number.png"></image>
<a xlink:href="https://www.store.com/products/link1">
    <rect class="table_number" x="46" y="54" width="86" height="70"></rect>
</a>
<a xlink:href="https://www.store.com/products/link2">
    <rect class="table_number" x="171" y="56" width="84" height="69"></rect>
</a>
<a xlink:href="https://www.store.com/products/link3">
    <rect class="table_number" x="292" y="59" width="82" height="65"></rect>
</a>
<a xlink:href="https://www.store.com/products/link4">
    <rect class="table_number" x="408" y="59" width="85" height="70"></rect>
</a>
</svg>
<script>
getData();

async function getData(){
const response= await fetch('myurl')
console.log(response);

//Help here

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

1. I changed `<a xlink:href=""` to  `<a href=""` because  `xlink:href` is deprecated as per [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/xlink:href). The advantage of it is now we can use `querySelectorAll` like this `document.querySelectorAll("[href="some_url"]");` to get the target element
2. After we get the taget `<a>` element, we target its child, in this case, the `<rect>` element using `item.querySelectorAll(":scope > rect");`. After that, add a class to it using `item.classList.add("red")`. `red` is a class that turn opacity to 1 so that the box turns red.

```html
<style>
  .table_number {
    fill: red;
   opacity: 0;
  }
  
  .red {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  
</style>

<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 540 159">
  <image width="540" height="159" xlink:href="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0573/4478/6617/files/tables_number.png">       </image>
  <a href="https://www.store.com/products/link1">
    <rect class="table_number" x="46" y="54" width="86" height="70"></rect>
  </a>
  <a href="https://www.store.com/products/link2">
    <rect class="table_number" x="171" y="56" width="84" height="69"></rect>
  </a>
  <a href="https://www.store.com/products/link3">
    <rect class="table_number" x="292" y="59" width="82" height="65"></rect>
  </a>
  <a href="https://www.store.com/products/link4">
    <rect class="table_number" x="408" y="59" width="85" height="70"></rect>
  </a>
</svg>

<script>
  getData();

  async function getData(){
    // const response= await fetch('myurl')
    // console.log(response);

    // mock response variable
    const response = {
      "documents": [
        {
          "_id": "646fd0fbe269fac6c8374c9e",
          "id": "gid://Product/7592907636921",
          "status": false,
          "url": "https://www.store.com/products/link1"
        },
      ]
    }

    // Help here
    response.documents.filter(d => !d.status).map(data => {
      // Find <a> elements with the href attribute equals data url
      const ALinks = document.querySelectorAll(`[href="${data.url}"]`);
      ALinks.forEach((item) => {
        let allChildren = item.querySelectorAll(":scope > rect");
         allChildren.forEach((item) => item.classList.add("red"));
      });
    })
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Two more questions:
1. How can I validate if changing "status=true" the red fill is removed.
2. Instead of setting a red square, is it possible to set an "X"?

Comment: inside the `map` callback function, wrap everything inside an if block, like `if (!data.status) { const Alinks = ....}`

Comment: or `filter` the response before `map` it (l edited my code snippet)